# How to show/hide menu based on checkbox(s) value with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, checkbox

**Update 10/4/18:** I've updated the Snippet to reflected changes for anyone who may stumble upon this thread in seek of help.  Existing check-boxes and newly added check-boxes will open/close the menu.

```js
var statusChangeMenu, activeList, itemCheckBox, activeItems;
statusChangeMenu = document.getElementById("status-change-menu");
activeList = document.getElementById("active-items");
itemCheckBox = activeList.getElementsByClassName("item-checkbox");
activeItems = activeList.getElementsByClassName("active-item-text");

function addNewItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  activeList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "\
<li class=\"item\">\
  <input class=\"item-checkbox\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\" />\
  <span class=\"active-item-text\"></span>\
  <button class=\"btn-complete\">complete</button>\
</li>");
  activeItems[0].textContent = document.getElementById("new-item-text").value;
}

document.getElementById("btn-add-item").addEventListener("click", addNewItem, false);
activeList.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = itemCheckBox.length; i < len || (i = 0); ++i) {
    if (itemCheckBox[i].checked) {
      i = 40;
      break;
    }
  }
  statusChangeMenu.style.height = i + "px";
}, false);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #393F4D;
}
header{
    background-color: #1D1E22;
    color: #FEDA6A;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
main{
    background-color: #707070;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
#status-change-menu{
    background-color: rgb(218, 123, 123);
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
#status-change-menu>button>img{
    height: 40px;  
}
form{
    background-color: #D4D4DC;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
}
#new-item-text{
    width: 100%;
}
#btn-add-item{
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px; 
}
.item-list-container{
    background-color: #D4D4DC;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
}
.item{
    background-color: rgb(165, 233, 222);
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr max-content;
    grid-template-rows: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.item-checkbox{
    grid-column: 1/2; 
  width: 30px;
  margin:auto;
}
.active-item-text{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    background: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-complete{
 grid-column: 3/4;
}
.item>input{
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body id="the-list">
    <header>
        <h1>The List V4</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form action="#">
            <textarea name="textbox" id="new-item-text" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="btn-add-item">Add</button>
        </form>
        <div id="status-change-menu" class="change-menu">
          <h3>Status Change Menu</h3>
            <button class="btn-bar-hold">BTN1<img src="img/btn_hold.svg" alt=""></button>
            <button class="btn-bar-delete">BTN2<img src="img/btn_delete.svg" alt=""></button>
        </div>
        <div class="item-list-container">
            <ul id="active-items" class="item-list">
                <li class="item">
                  <input class="item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                  <span class="active-item-text">random text text random</span>
                  <button class="btn-complete">complete</button>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                  <input class="item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                  <span class="active-item-text">random text text random</span>
                  <button class="btn-complete">complete</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

---

I'm working on a simple checklist web app using pure vanilla HTML, CSS, javascript.  I've been stuck in one part all weekend.  Hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm missing or doing wrong.  Here's where I'm at.

### **My Goal**

Whenever an item in the checklist (ul) is selected (via checkbox), a hidden menu slides out with various options to manipulate the selected item(s).  The menu must stay visible if any of the checkboxes on the list are checked.  The menu must close if no checkboxes are checked.

### **Where I'm Stuck**

I'm able to get the menu to slide out during a 'change' event of the checkbox, but I can't get the menu element to react after the initial change event.  During debugging, it also appears the menu element is not reacting to the checkbox is in a 'checked' state, but simply just reacting to the checkbox being changed in general.  Here's the JS code I have, but I've tested various other configurations with no success.

**Code Pen with Full Code** & Snippet of related JS code below.
Updated Codepen 10/4/18
https://codepen.io/skazx/pen/mzeoEO?

```
var itemCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
var statusChangeMenu = document.getElementById("status-change-menu")

for(var i = 0 ; i < itemCheckBox.length; i++){
  itemCheckBox[i].addEventListener("change", function(){

    if (!itemCheckBox.checked)
    {statusChangeMenu.style.height = "40px";}
    else 
    {statusChangeMenu.style.height = "0px";}
  })}
```

I've read a few dozen different post and articles, but most were related to only having 1 checkbox or used jquery. Let me know if you need any further details. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemCheckBox` refers to a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), not an individual element, so saying `itemCheckBox.checked` doesn't really make sense.

You should be checking if **any** checkbox in the list is checked, which you can use with the `.some()` function, like so:

Here's a working demo

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemCheckBox.length; i++) {
  itemCheckBox[i].addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.checked) {
      statusChangeMenu.style.height = "40px";
    } else {
      statusChangeMenu.style.height = "0px";
    }
  });
}
```

```js
var itemCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var statusChangeMenu = document.getElementById("status-change-menu");
function changeHandler (event) {
  // get the list of checkboxes in real time in case any were added to the DOM
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var anyChecked = [].some.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox) { return checkbox.checked; });
  // alternatively (instead of using .some()):
  // var anyChecked = false;
  // checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
  //   if (checkbox.checked) {
  //     anyChecked = true;
  //   }
  // });

  if (anyChecked) {
    statusChangeMenu.style.height = "40px";
  } else {
    statusChangeMenu.style.height = "0px";
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < itemCheckBox.length; i++) {
  itemCheckBox[i].addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
}

for (var i = itemCheckBox.length; i < itemCheckBox.length + 2; i++) {
  // add some checkboxes dynamically
  var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
  var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
  newLabel.innerText = "Checkbox " + (i + 1);
  newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
  // -- IMPORTANT-- bind event listener on dynamically added checkbox
  newCheckbox.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
  newLabel.appendChild(newCheckbox);
  newLabel.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  document.body.appendChild(newLabel);
}
```

```css
#status-change-menu {
  height: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="status-change-menu">I should be visible if any checkboxes are checked</div>
<label>Checkbox 1<input type="checkbox"/></label><br/>
<label>Checkbox 2<input type="checkbox"/></label><br/>
<label>Checkbox 3<input type="checkbox"/></label><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you! The some() method is perfect! That makes complete sense, testing the NodeList to see if any elements within it pass the test for being checked. Thank you for your breakdown and example snippet.

Comment: Seems like any newly added checkboxes are not triggering the 'eventListener'.  Do you think I should be looking into using event delegation for these dynamically created list items containing new checkboxes?

Comment: @skaz `querySelectorAll` returns a **static** list of elements, so if any are added to the DOM, they will not be looked at, nor will they have the change handler on them. Either event delegation or just attaching the change handler when an element is added to the DOM will work for handling the events on newly added items. The only other change you will have to make is instead of iterating over `itemCheckBox` in the event listener, you will have to grab the updated list of checkboxes by re-issuing the `var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: @skaz I have updated my post to include the changes I mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

mhodges is correct in that itemCheckBox is a NodeList, not an individual element. Another issue is that you are trying to test if the box that changed is checked, and if it isn't, you are closing the menu. As you described, that is not what you want.

You need another way to check to see if all check boxes are unchecked before you close the menu. A simple way to do that is just another inner loop in the onChange function:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < itemCheckBox.length; i++){
  itemCheckBox[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
    showMenu = false
    for(var j = 0; j < itemCheckBox.length; j++)
      {
        if(itemCheckBox[j].checked)
          showMenu = true
      }
    if (showMenu)
      {statusChangeMenu.style.height = "40px";} 
    else 
      {statusChangeMenu.style.height = "0px";}
})}
```

Heres a modified [Snippet](https://codepen.io/SSimcox/pen/XxmWZJ)

Comment: Thank you Simcox, your code also works!  I appreciate the example, it showed me some things I was also doing wrong with other methods I had tried last night.